# NP-R60Y (ноут) под 7 виндой доступно 2,75 Гб из 4, под Вистой все 4

Tags: windows, память, железо, драйвер, ноутбук

Обновлял ноут Samsung NP-R60Y (вместо жесткого воткнул ССД, викинул две линейки оперативы по 1Гб, воткнул 2 по 2Гб). Поставил 7 Винду. Немного пришлось поморочиться с видеодрайвером (на оф. сайте драйвера только для Висты и ХР) Но всё-таки поставил.

Сейчас напрягает то, что из 4 Гб оперативы пишет доступно 2,75. Вместо ССД подключил старый жесткий с Вистой — там доступно всё 4 Гб. Т.е. дело не в настройках БИОСа. Подозрения на то, что нужен драйвер на чипсет, который найти ой как не просто для 7 Винды.

Насколько реально заставить работать под семёркой этот раритет? Искать драйвер на чипсет, или дело не в нём?

Comment: Винда х86 или х64?

Comment: Кстати вы случано не 7 starter поставили?

Comment: @AlexZaslavskis, нет, не стартер. 64 бита. Подозреваю, что дело в драйверах чипсета

Comment: Хотя и видеокарта что то могла откусить. Или у вас дискретка? Кстати модель ноута не скините?

Comment: Ну а в чём проблема? Дрова должны лежать на сайте Самса. Если старые и не нравятся - выкачивай zip'ы с drp.su. Всё установишь - тогда и приходи.

Comment: Попробуйте драйвера по ID искать.

Comment: https://www.dns-shop.ru/technical-support/driver-search-by-id-info/

Comment: @donRumata, в том и проблема, что только для Висты и ХР

Comment: @AlexZaslavskis Так я для видео поставил. Не ясно что для памяти нужно

Comment: Ну. От висты по больше части подходит. На drp.su по devid искал?

Comment: @donRumata, там драйверпак только для автоматической установки, он всю систему испортил, кучу всего наставил, а нужного как раз и нет.

Comment: Эммм... там есть поиск по devid. Вбиваешь интересующую железку, тебе предлагают скачать exe. Выбираешь zip. Качаешь, распаковываешь, натравливаешь пункт "поиск драйверов" из оснастки на эту папку. Драйвер ставится. Долго, зато надёжно и никаких Амиг не прилетает. А про автоматическую установку - есть старая пословица про молитву и лоб.